# Docker Errors : error checking context: 'can't stat '/home/xyz/docker_experiments''

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04

I'm running docker [Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build a04f55b] on an Ubuntu machine.

Simply carrying out a very simple exercise from docker in order to build a docker image : https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#apppy

On running the following command

```
sudo docker build -t friendlyhello .
```

I get the following error

```
error checking context: 'can't stat '/home/xyz/docker_experiments''.
```

I understand this is something to do with apparmour and permissions.

As requested this is the Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:2.7-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Comment: Can you include the actual Dockerfile you're using in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably a permissions issue.

2 things you can try:

- Try removing the sudo. If you've configured Docker correctly when you installed it, you shouldn't need to use sudo on every command. I can update this answer with the code to do that if you are running into this trouble once I get to work.
- Try moving your dockerfile out of your ubuntu directory into a directory that you've set up and have access to. Try chmodding that directory so you have all the access you need.

`mkdir /docker/test
cp . /docker/test
cd /docker/test
sudo docker build -t friendlyhello .`

Comment: Thanks.  

This was a simply permissions issues.  
Creating a new directory under users elevating the privileges worked